# Meaning of はにゃせ or はにやせ

Tags: meaning, slang, greetings

Context: two people are walking on a street and a tramp says to them:

> はにゃせー、バカヤロー

I'm not sure if it's はにゃせ or はにやせ, because it is written in small fonts, I am attaching an image so you can tell. Could it be a Korean greeting? Thank you for your help!

[image]

Comment: +1 for the Korean greeting part.  That thought crossed my mind as well.

Comment: I thought a cat character was speaking when I looked at the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two possibilities (besides the Korean theory).

「はにゃせ～～」 would be the drunk and/or sleepy man's pronunciation of

1)  「離{はな}せ！」 =  "Leave me alone!", "Let me go!", etc.

2)  「話{はな}せ！」 = "Tell me!"

The first interpretation would be more likely, but that is just speculation given the limited context.

「はにやせ」 with the normal-size 「や」 would make no sense at all.