# Any common, noteworthy changes in speech when a 日本人 is totally wasted?

Tags: spoken-language

Now, I've never met a Japanese person who's gotten hammered, much less creepily observed their speaking patterns. Thus, I must ask: are there any common or noteworthy changes in how people speak while they're drunk?

In English we don't really get much, just slurring and rudeness; but Japanese is littered with context rules, politeness rules, etc. you know, the kind of things that would assume some degree of spacial or contextual awareness. Thus, I'm just curious if anything emerges when a boy/girl speaks while moderately inebriated, not to far gone, but by no means sober.

Comment: I don't think it's fundamentally different across cultures - it all depends on how drunk you are and how much of a jerk you are as a person.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most real people just get cheerful and talkative when drunk. At izakaya people still naturally use basic keigo. Depending on the situation people can choose to use a bit less polite (and thus more friendly) word choice. But probably this is an almost universal tendency. I can't think of a noteworthy change unique to the Japanese language.

When too drunk, speech can become very slurred and impolite; for example see [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/23543/5010) and [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/46413/5010). At nightlife districts you might occasionally see a drunkard who speaks very rudely to a police officer. Such a person is called [酒癖が悪い人](http://jisho.org/search/%E9%85%92%E7%99%96).

Comment: Oh ya, I guess Keigo would be somewhat reflexive, wouldn't it.

Comment: @Tirous Languages are more or less reflex in brain, or being a native speaker is.